# How can I display instagram block with parse_block?

Tags: block-editor, embed

I have a big problem. I wrote this code:

```
$blocks = parse_blocks( $post->post_content );

foreach ( $blocks as $block ) {
  if( $block['blockName'] != '' ) {
     $blocks_2[] .= render_block( $block );
  }
}
$num_blocks = cont($blocks_2);

for ($i = 2; $i <= $num_blocks; $i++) {
  echo $blocks_2[$i];
}
```

Everything is great, but it doesn't display my code blocks (instagram, twitter) in embed format, just as a url.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Keep in mind this code doesn't account for nested blocks, you need to use recursion to handle that. Likewise there's a function to serialize the blocks that should be used. A `foreach ( $blocks_2 as $index => $block ) {` can avoid the need for the `$num_blocks` variable too, and there's a typo `cont` should be `count`

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions! I solved the problem and it works ok. Only for simple blocks. But that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `the_content` filter on the rendered blocks

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions! It was as it should have been.